# Get first letter of document?

Tags: javascript, input

I need to get and alert the first letter of that document with JavaScript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<P>Sententia est.</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I tried to do this this way:

```js
var littera = document[0];
alert(littera);
```

It alerts not `<`, but `undefined`. How can I get the first letter of the document?

Comment: document is not string object

Comment: You cannot access the innerHTML/outerHTML of document.

Comment: Do you want to say the letter "S" of the `<p>Sententia est.</p>` ?

Comment: Do you want the `<` of `<P>Sententia est.</P>` or `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`?

Comment: @pang I want the `<` of `<P>Sententia est.</P>`, but there already is an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <script>
            var littera = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
            alert(littera[0]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <BODY>
        <P>Sententia est.</P>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `documentElement`. The first letter is `S`. This can be alerted using `nextElementSibling`.

```js
alert(document.body.firstChild.nextElementSibling.innerHTML[0]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <P>Sententia est.</P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

If you need it to alert `<`, then you need to get the `innerHTML` of the body itself.

```js
alert(document.body.innerHTML.trim()[0]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <P>Sententia est.</P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

There are other ways to do as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/sh4359o2/)

```
var littera = document.children[0].innerHTML[0];
alert(littera);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine ....

```
var littera = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML.charAt(0);
alert(littera);
```

This code output is **'S'**
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nadimsajib/30jdo7ho/1/)